# Please what has gone wrong with these transformations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let the equality $$x^2-y^4=6$$ define $y$ as a function of $x,$ where both variables are real. The problem I set out to solve was to find the second derivative of $y$ with regard to $x,$ and I found an antinomy awaiting me; this is what I seek explanation for -- what have I done wrong, because presently I can't figure this out by myself.

So, upon differentiating the equation with the above assumptions and simplifying, one obtains $$2y^3y'=x.$$ Now, this is where things went funny; normally one would solve for $y'$ and then differentiate it to get $$y''=\frac{2y^4-3x^2}{4y^7};$$ but I thought, why bother with all that when one could simply differentiate one more time (and so far as I can see this is consistent with all the previous assumptions, no?); indeed, there are cases when one couldn't explicitly solve for $y',$ so that one would be obliged simply to follow what I actually did.

In any case, upon differentiating that first order equation again, one eventually obtains
$$y''=\frac{y-3x}{2y^4}.$$
Well, although one might be a little flustered at first, as I was, one might think that perhaps both values for $y''$ might reduce to the same expression upon using the original relation, but if one does that to simplify $\frac{2y^4-3x^2}{4y^7},$ it only becomes $-\frac{x^2+12}{4y^7}$, which doesn't make things look any better. Indeed, one can show that this could never happen, for upon setting the two expressions for $y''$ equal to each other and simplifying, the resulting equation should be identically true at all points of $\mathbf R^2$ where $y''$ exists, so that if one sets $y=1$ and uses the fact that (from the original relation) $x^2=7,$ we get $6-2=7+12,$ which clearly shows that the two  expressions for $y''$ are not identically equal indeed, as one imagines they should be.

Could someone please explain what's going on here? What have I done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like when you differentiate $2y^3y'$, you got the part $(2y^3)'y'$ wrong in that you forgot one of the $y'$.

Comment: @cr001 That was what happened. I had got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2y^3y'=x$$

Differentiating again,

$$2y^3y''+6y^2(y')^2=1$$

$$2y^3y''+6y^2\left( \frac{x}{2y^3}\right)^2=1$$

$$2y^3y''+\frac32\left( \frac{x^2}{y^4}\right)=1$$

Divide by $2y^3$ everywhere,

$$y''+\frac34\left( \frac{x^2}{y^7}\right)=\frac1{2y^3}$$

and we get

$$y''=\frac{2y^4-3x^2}{4y^7}$$

Do check if the line after you differentiate the first derivative directly is correct.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I got $2y^3y''+6y^2y'=1,$ so it follows that I forgot to differentiate $y$ again in that second term. Thanks.